# manage.py broken after update of appengine

Tags: djangoappengine

I updated appengine and now manage.py is broken, this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "manage.py", line 18, in 
    InstallAppengineHelperForDjango()
  File "\workspace\Project\src\appengine_django__init__.py", line
545, in InstallAppengineHelperForDjango
    InstallDjangoModuleReplacements()
  File "\workspace\Project\src\appengine_django__init__.py", line
262, in InstallDjangoModuleReplacements
    import django.db
  File "\workspace\Project\src\django.zip\django\db__init__.py", l
ine 39, in

File "\workspace\Project\src\appengine_django\db\base.py", line 1
17, in **init**
    self._setup_stubs()
  File "\workspace\Project\src\appengine_django\db\base.py", line 1
28, in _setup_stubs
    from google.appengine.tools import dev_appserver_main
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\de
v_appserver_main.py", line 90, in 
    from google.appengine.tools import appcfg
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 59, in 
    from google.appengine.tools import appengine_rpc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pengine_rpc.py", line 24, in 
    import fancy_urllib
ImportError: No module named fancy_urllib

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the same with the recent [App Engine SDK 1.3.6](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html) release + [Google App Engine Helper for Django](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/appengine_helper_for_django.html).  Google is [aware of the issue](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/e2648a47b3df5876/6e93f6150eca4a52?lnk=raot#1d79d31617611b7a) and a ticket has been opened here: http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/issues/detail?id=178; please star it to escalate.

A couple options:

1. wait for them to issue a patch
2. rollback to [1.3.5](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/downloads/list?can=4&q=1.3.5&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+Size+DownloadCount).  I had to uninstall 1.3.6 before reinstalling 1.3.5.

Comment: I know I am late, but I am putting some closure to this. I rolledback to 1.3.5